# Get random address/coordinates in a specified town

Tags: ios, google-maps, random, street-address

Is there any way to give Google Maps API or a similar API a town name and have it return a random address inside the town? I was hoping to be able to get the data as a JSON so I could parse it with SwiftyJSON in XCode and use it, but I can't seem to find any way to get the address in the first place. If coordinates would be easier to get, then those would work too, as long as its random and inside the town borders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [Google Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro). It allows you to query for place information on a variety of categories, such as: establishments, prominent points of interest, geographic locations, and more. You can search for places either by proximity or a text string. A Place Search returns a list of places along with summary information about each place.

A [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) lets you search for places within a specified area. You can refine your search request by supplying keywords or specifying the type of place you are searching for.

A Nearby Search request is an HTTP URL of the following form:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?parameters
```

where output may be either xml or JSON values.

And if you want either address or coordinates, you can use [Geocoding](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-hybrid-plus/topics/geocoding.html) for it. Here i found a [tutorial](http://mhorga.org/2015/08/14/geocoding-in-ios.html) on how to use Geocoding in IOS.